# MySQL Select count, group by distinct - two columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, distinct

I want to get on Mysql :

- Count number of rows where column done is < 2
- Get the runner id
- but group if runnerA and runnerB are same person.

So I want to know the number of rows where each runner is present, even if he is in runnerA or runnerB.

An exemple :

My datas :

| id | id_runnerA | id_runnerB | done |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 20 | 12 | 1 |
| 3 | 12 | 1 | 3 |

The result should be :

| id_runner | count |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 2 |
| 20 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it might be

```
SELECT
  id_runner, count(*)
FROM
  (
    SELECT id_runnera as id_runner FROM t WHERE done < 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id_runnerb FROM t WHERE done < 2
  ) x
GROUP BY
  id_runner
```

But it'd be helpful to see some more test data

Comment: I have to learn about 'UNION ALL'

Comment: `UNION ALL` sticks two result sets together one on top of the other. the number and type of columns must match. Union all keeps all rows from both. `UNION`, by comparison, de-dupes the two resultsets using all values, so N 100% identical rows are squashed to one